# How can I properly increase C++11 std::atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

I'm new to multi-thread programming, and I found the `std::atomic` in C++11.

So, I tried to figure out how much time atomic operations take.

I tried this code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr int NUM_THREADS = 8;
constexpr int LIMIT = 100000;

atomic<int> sum = 0;

void foo(int idx) {
    while (true) {
        if (sum.load() >= LIMIT) {
            return;
        }
        sum.fetch_add(1);
    }
}
```

with `main`:

```
int main(void) {
    thread threads[NUM_THREADS];

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        threads[i] = thread(&foo, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    auto du = high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

    cout << "computing time\t\t" << duration_cast<milliseconds>(du).count() << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "number of thread\t" << NUM_THREADS << endl;
    cout << "sum\t\t\t" << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But `sum` is not always same as `LIMIT`.

To my knowledge, the atomic operations thread-safe when 'called'. So, yes, I think my code is wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to make this work properly.

How can I get a correct result with that `main`?

(well, this version will make `sum` and `LIMIT` equal, but I think this isn't a good way...)

```
void foo(int idx) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT / NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        sum.fetch_add(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one cant work because your check and your increment are two separate operations, thus 2 threads could potentially read something below LIMIT and both decide to increment.

Comment: Your problem isn't how to increment an atomic -- your problem is how to atomically perform a sequence of *two* operations.

Comment: You need either http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange or mutex.

Comment: Right, so my mistake was performing **two** atomic operations so cannot be atomic. Maybe I was confused with mutex. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was said in the comments your problem is that the variable is changed by another thread between the time you load it and the time you increment it.

You could change your loop e.g. like this to fix it:

```
while (true) {
    auto current = sum.load();        
    if (current >= LIMIT) {
        return;
    }
    auto next = current + 1;
    sum.compare_exchange_strong(current, next));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator++` is atomic on atomic types, so all you need to do is this:

```
void foo(int idx) {
    while (true) {
        if (sum++ >= LIMIT) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Once one of the threads increments `sum` to `LIMIT`, the rest of the threads will also see that the value is greater than or equal to `LIMIT` and return. There is one risk here: if the number of threads is greater than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - LIMIT` then one of the later threads will increment `sum` past the maximum value for an `int`. As long as `LIMIT` is sensible <g> this won't be a problem.